# Display sheet within init at initial app lunch

Tags: swift, swiftui

I created an init like this:

```
init() {
        // Show what's new on the update from App Store
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "appStoreUpdateNotification_2.2.0") {

            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "appStoreUpdateNotification_2.2.0")
        }
    }
```

How can I include the sheet there? Until now I was using a button to display it. This is to show the sheet when I update the app to inform the users of changes

Comment: It is the `init` of what exactly? Genrally, you can set some variable (eg. `@State`) and present a sheet using `.sheet(isPresented:)`

Comment: @pawello2222 the init is kind of redundant, the question is how to make the sheet present itself without having to click a button, so when the init kicks in, it presents itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting a `@State` variable and use it to present a sheet:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var isShowingModal: Bool = false

    init() {
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "appStoreUpdateNotification_2.2.0") {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "appStoreUpdateNotification_2.2.0")
            _isShowingModal = .init(initialValue: true)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("")
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingModal) {
            SomeOtherView()
        }
    }
}
```